# How to eliminate auto generated row values (numbers) in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I am trying to apply tm in R for a csv file and then append it to original content for comparing to a new csv file, but while the result is produced it gives just the text values while appending to file row values are created with it. How do I eliminate these row numbers?

After applying tm to a file, I am converting the result to a data frame with this code:

```
result<- data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(b, `[`)), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

The output of this would be:

```
Customer
1    c c petrochemical  
2    c c plastics  
3    c  dwght  
4    cit systems  pacific  
5    cnh industrial services srl
```

But after moving this to a csv file

```
write.csv(res, file="result26.csv")
r2 <- read.table(file="result26.csv",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

the output is like this

```
1                 6, conoco phillips 0312  
2                      7, conocophillips   
3                    8, dfk laurence varnay
4                         9, dtz worldwide 
5    10, electro motive maintenance operati
```

How do I eliminate the row numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
write.csv(res, file="result26.csv", row.names=F)
r2 <- read.table(file="result26.csv",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

Use `row.names=F` to eliminate the row indices.